# Probability Question (Airplane Motors)

Tags: probability

I have a probability question:

Suppose some airplane motors fail with the probability "Q", no matter which motor we are talking about, and that the plane makes a successful flight if at least half of the motors are working. For which "Q" values we should prefer a 2-motors to a 4-motors?

I can't understand why for any Q value (which is the same for both) we would prefer to use 2 motors instead of 4, since last is much better and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where $2$ motors is better than $4$.  Take $Q=.40$.

For $2$ motors, the probability of a successful flight is equal to $1-$ P(both motors fail)$=1-.4^2=.84$.

For $4$ motors, the probability of a successful flight is equal to $1-$P($3$ or $4$ motors fail)$=1-4\cdot (.4^3)(.6)-.4^4=.8208$.

So in this case your chance of a successful flight is higher with two motors.

Can you generalize this reasoning?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The answer is when Q > 1/3 . How could I get to that result knowing only the Probability of 1/2 (motors for successful flight)?

Comment: Look at the set-up for the $Q=0.4$ case in the answer I posted.  Then try to do it with a general $Q$.  This should lead you to an inequality that you can solve.

Comment: Can you explain me why the Prob of 3 or 4 motors fail is 1 - 4 * (.4^3)(.6) - .4^4 ?

Comment: @paw88789 That is a very neat fourth degree inequality with nice roots. A nice application of polynomials indeed!

Comment: @imranfat Thanks.

Comment: @PedroB: The probability that $3$ motors fail is ${4\choose 3}(.4)^3(.6)=4(.4)^3(.6)$ (binomial probability.  The probability that $4$ motors fail is ${4\choose 4}.4^3=.4^3$ (also binomial probability).